# Executar função ao clicar em qualquer elemento do tipo

Tags: javascript

Quero que, ao clicar em qualquer link [elemento 'a'], algo aconteça.

Já tentei o código abaixo, com `getElementsByTagName` mas não obtive sucesso.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quando você seleciona vários elementos, é lhe retornado um objeto *array-like* com todos os elementos que correspondem à busca.

No caso, `document.getElementsByTagName('a')` vai retornar um [`HTMLCollection` vivo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) com todos os elementos a encontrados, mesmo que seja um só.

Para você colocar um *event listener* em cada um dos elementos encontrados, você precisa percorrer por cada elemento dessa lista.

Desta forma:

```
// Seleciona todos os elementos de determinada tag
var elementos_a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

// Percorre os elementos. 
for (var i = 0; i < elementos_a.length; i++) {
    /* Adiciona o evento em cada um dos elementos por meio do seu índice no array */        
    elementos_a[i].onclick = function() {
        alert('Olá, eu sou o elemento número ' + i);
    }
}
```

---

Outra forma de fazer isso é usando *event delegation*. Nesse padrão, você cria um lista de ações disponíveis e diz a cada elemento qual dessas ações ele deve executar quando determinado evento for disparado.

#### Vantagens da delegação de eventos

- A vantagem desse padrão é que você não precisa percorrer todos os
  elementos encontrados e adicionar uma função *callback* em cada um
  deles.  Neste padrão, você adiciona o *callback* apenas no elemento
  pai, e então, quando você clicar em um elemento filho, o evento será
  disparado no elemento filho e, só depois, no elemento pai.
- Dessa forma, você pode adicionar novos elementos dinamicamente e não precisa adicionar um *callback* diretamente neles. Você só precisa dizer que ação ele deve executar

Como isso é possível? O jeito padrão (*default*) que a maioria dos browsers usa para propagar eventos é o *capture*. No *event delegation*, o padrão utilizado é o *bubbling*.
Basicamente, o capture propaga o evento do elemento pai até o elemento filho (de cima pra baixo). Já o *bubbling* propaga do elemento filho até o elemento pai (de baixo pra cima).
[Saiba mais aqui](https://imasters.com.br/front-end/javascript/javascript-bubbling-e-capturing/?trace=1519021197&source=single)

**Exemplo:**

```js
var todosItems = document.querySelector('#items');
var relatorio = document.querySelector('#relatorio');


// As ações disponíveis
var acoes = {
  /**
  Mostra o conteúdo do elemento
  no relatorio  
  **/
  mostrarItem: function(elemento) {
    // Este código não importa
    var texto = elemento.textContent;
    relatorio.textContent = texto;
  },
  
  /**
  Edita o conteúdo do elemento
  **/
  editarConteudo: function(elemento) {
    // Este código não importa
    elemento.contentEditable = "true";
    elemento.focus();
    elemento.onblur = function() {
      elemento.contentEditable = "false";
    }
  },

  // Colore o elemento por meio segundo
  colorir: function(elemento) {
    // Este código não importa
    elemento.style.color = "red";        
    setTimeout(function() {elemento.style.color = 'black'}, 500);
  }

}


/**
Adiciona o evento click apenas no elemento
que é pai dos items (ul#items)
**/
todosItems.addEventListener('click', function(evento) {
  /**
  Quando algum elemento for clicado dentro do
  elemento pai, "evento.target" representará
  esse mesmo elemento (clicado)
  **/
  var itemClicado = evento.target;
  
  /**
  Nome da ação que o elemento deve executar
  é extraído da propriedade data-acao=""
  **/
  var nomeDaAcao = itemClicado.dataset.acao;
  
  /**
  Pega a função que corresponde à ação desejada
  na nossa lista de açṍes (variável acoes)
  Verifica também se a ação requerida existe
  na lista de ações usando uma condição ternária
  **/
  var executar = acoes[nomeDaAcao] ? acoes[nomeDaAcao] : null;
  
  /**
  Se a ação existir, executa ela passando o 
  elemento clicado como argumento
  **/
  if (executar != null) {
    executar(itemClicado)
  }
  
/**
False significa que o evento deve ser do tipo
bubble, e não do tipo capture.
Veja mais sobre bubble e capture no link que deixei.
Eles são a base do event delegation
**/
}, false)
```

```html
<ul id="items">
  <!-- Estes dois têm suas têm suas informações
  exibidas quando você clica neles -->
  <li data-acao="mostrarItem" >Smartphone</li>
  <li data-acao="mostrarItem" >Refrigerador</li>
  
  <!-- Estes dois você pode editar ao clicar -->
  <li data-acao="editarConteudo" >Notebook</li>
  <li data-acao="editarConteudo" >Liquidificador</li>

  <!-- Estes dois vão mudar de cor ao clicar -->
  <li data-acao="colorir" >Geladeira</li>
  <li data-acao="colorir" >Fogão</li>
<ul>

<p id="relatorio"> <p>
```